# Help understanding how to modify lay out of pages within drupal

Tags: theming

I have built my website locally and I am trying to have three pictures display on all pages of the website. Those three pictures need to be on one line:

Now I have the pictures as such:

- picture 1
- picture 2
- picture 3

I need:

> picture 1, picture 2, picture 3

I understand that I need to create a css file that will alter the structure of all the pages to display the pictures. I have done that following example on the net.

```
.field-type-image {
  float: left;
  padding-left:20px;
}
```

Now I have edited the .info file of my website to link the style.css but the pictures are still not showing the way I want. Moreover, they are only showing on one page.

What am I missing here ?

I have used firebug to try to find the css page on which I could have made the change for the pictures to appear but there were none. That is why I decided to create the style.css

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal answers. This site is just for Drupal specific questions, but this is a question on CSS so you would be better asking this on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). However one thing to check is to make sure the CSS is actually included on the page. You can do this in Firebug by checking the CSS tab.

Comment: @zongo: You should at least tell us how you have been including the images, and provide a link to the page. Otherwise, there is no way really to tell what you are missing.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are embedding the images in a block which you then show on all your pages.

If you reference a background-image from your style sheet as in url(../images/hello.jpg) all works fine because the style sheet, no matter what page you are looking at, references images from the style sheet directory as a base . If you embed an image tag on a page your img url will not be correct for pages of different depths as the page's url changes, and it is the page url that is the base. You have two quick solutions:

1. Pathalogic module - it is a text input filter that will rewrite
   your embedded anchor and image paths automatically
2. PHP Filter - It is also a text input filter. Rewrite the path using the l() function, or concatenate it onto $base_url in a PHP snippet. This method is not preferred and support for the PHP Filter has been dropped in Drupal 8.

**And as to the css and theming problems:**

Marinelli is using a 960 grid system. There are lots of information on the web available on that and I suggest you read up on that.

In short, you must add appropriate classes to your images which will then take care of the css on your behalf. To float 3 images horizontally you need to add the following classes to your images.

image 1. class="alpha grid_4"
image 2. class="grid_4"
image 3. class="grid_4 omega"

And depending on your use case you might need to do a clearfix on the parent container.

Comment: @all, thank you so much for your replies. I do understantd that it is not easy for you guys as I expressed myself in a very limited way :) (part of being newbie). I tried two different ways. The first was to use the GUI to embed the picture in a post. That worked well but I gave up on that solution as it was not showing the way I wanted. The second time, I used: `img src="image.gif"` for the three pictures but then I did not achieve what I intended since the pictures are all lined up on one page vertically and not horizontaly.

Comment: quick  amendment: I do not know how to post an  excerpt of what I am trying to achieve since everything is done locally on nothing is non the net :) If anyone has any suggestion ? I am using Marinelli theme. I have followed the how to on how to actually use the subtheme. All is working great besides the modifications I am trying to make.